# Direct count, not incremental count solution

Tags: python, dictionary, combinations, counter

This produces a count of frequency of tuples between 3 list, can it be done via direct count not incremental count (not `+=`)?

For clarification, I would like to work around having to increase the value of the key for every iteration using `+=` and directly apply the count to corresponding pair

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import combinations

dd = defaultdict(int)

L1 = ["cat", "toe", "man"]
L2 = ["cat", "toe", "ice"]
L3 = ["cat", "hat", "bed"]

for L in [L1, L2, L3]:
    for pair in map(frozenset, (combinations(L, 2))):
        dd[pair] += 1
```

> ```
> defaultdict(int,
>             {frozenset({'cat', 'toe'}): 2,
>              frozenset({'cat', 'man'}): 1,
>              frozenset({'man', 'toe'}): 1,
>              frozenset({'cat', 'ice'}): 1,
>              frozenset({'ice', 'toe'}): 1,
>              frozenset({'cat', 'hat'}): 1,
>              frozenset({'bed', 'cat'}): 1,
>              frozenset({'bed', 'hat'}): 1})
> ```

Comment: What do you mean "by direct count"?  You can somewhat *obfuscate* the increment operation from the user-level source code, but I don't see how you plan to get the total without incrementing *anywhere*.

Comment: Without using `+=` in the process just getting directly applying the count to said pair

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counts are not *stored* anywhere, so iteration is unavoidable. But you can use `collections.Counter` with a generator expression to avoid an explicit `for` loop:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain, combinations

L1 = ["cat", "toe", "man"]
L2 = ["cat", "toe", "ice"]
L3 = ["cat", "hat", "bed"]

L_comb = [L1, L2, L3]

c = Counter(map(frozenset, chain.from_iterable(combinations(L, 2) for L in L_comb)))
```

Result:

```
Counter({frozenset({'cat', 'toe'}): 2,
         frozenset({'cat', 'man'}): 1,
         frozenset({'man', 'toe'}): 1,
         frozenset({'cat', 'ice'}): 1,
         frozenset({'ice', 'toe'}): 1,
         frozenset({'cat', 'hat'}): 1,
         frozenset({'bed', 'cat'}): 1,
         frozenset({'bed', 'hat'}): 1})
```

Comment: chain is a nice touch - both of you got me by 2 minutes.

Comment: Stiff competition out there for this solution although,  I fancy this `(Counter(tuple(sorted(pair)) for sublist in l4 for pair in combinations(sublist, 2)))`